# I have problem with accessing another python file variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have trouble with accessing another python file after writing it.

First of all I have a main file (called Ara-Engine)and then I have a file called post.
In the main file I wrote it with f.write() and then I closed it with f.close .
but when I want to import its variables to the main file with from post import* IT doesn't import the variables.

```
f=open('post.py' , 'w')
f.write('a'+fpt+'b')
f.close()
```

`#fpt is a variable in my main file`

```
from post import * #It doesnt work
```

Comment: What is the end goal here? To serialize data for storage that can be retrieved later? It's better to use something like JSON for that, not programatically writing a new python file and reading data in from it as if it was a variable.

Comment: use `with open` to write the data not in list

Comment: If you are just storing values in that file, try using pickle or json instead.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve here. But hacking a python file programatically is always a bad idea and just asking for trouble.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by hacking python file

Comment: What is the value of ``fpt``?

Comment: Look I am making sth like WordPress powered by combination of python and html as string and fpt is the first post in that html and a and b are html codes.

Comment: What you describe is not valid Python code, least of all a variable declaration; trying to import that makes no sense. Do you perhaps want to *read* back what you have written? Why don't you delay closing the initial file until you have written everything to it?

Answer (score 0):

You have not included everything in your question.
It should work, it imports variable as well as functions. See this example:

```
In [1]: f=open('s80post.py' , 'w')
   ...: f.write('''
   ...: x=5
   ...: def fun():
   ...:     print("hello")
   ...: ''')
   ...: f.close()
   ...: 
   ...: from s80post import *
   ...: print(x)
   ...: fun()
   ...: 
5
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Python files are a series of Python statements that can be interpreted and executed by the Python interpreter. If you really want to write a Python file programmatically, then you're going to have to write complete Python statements.

So for example, I think you want to store in a variable a string containing the contents of `fpt`, wrapped in the tags `a` and `b`. If you were to do this in Python is would be something like this:

```
fpt_str = 'a' + fpt + 'b'
```

So that's what you need to write to your file (though you need to evaluate the concatenation first so the file has the contents of `fpt`):

```
f.write('fpt_str = a' + fpt + 'b\n')
```

Now when you do something like `from blah import *` you'll have a valid Python module from which to import, so `fpt_str` will be defined.

Sooner or later you'll discover this is a messy way to store variables. Writing Python code from within Python code is cumbersome and error-prone. You'll probably want to consider one of the options that is designed for this purpose instead. Two popular methods are:

1. Write as JSON instead. A good options if you want a readable format.

Something like:

```
import json
json.dumps({ "fpt_str": 'a' + fpt + 'b' }, open('s80post.py' , 'w'))
```

2. Write as a Pickle instead. A good option if you want a compact format.

Something like:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump({ "fpt_str": 'a' + fpt + 'b' }, open('s80post.py' , 'wb'))
```